# How to view the query in Views 3?

Tags: views

I want to look at the MySQL query built by Views. In views 2 it just shows while I can't seem to find it in the View 3 UI. Is it still available?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can choose to display the query; it's a checkbox called "Show the SQL query" on the Views settings page (admin/structure/views/settings).

Comment: I was looking all over for it and it was right there.

Comment: There is also a drush commando do set some variables: drush views-dev

Comment: @Daniel Nice, I didn't know that one.

Comment: but I have to search 'drupal 7 views settings have  no Show the SQL query'drush views-dev  works for me.

Comment: I see this checkbox in the source code but it has "display:none" in the CSS style. Does this option depend on some other module or setting?

Comment: In Drupal 8 you can access this page directly in the answer path or go to Structure / Views (click on the Settings tab) and then select the options you want.